# How to get the Document's Title from a Web Browser control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, tabcontrol

I have created a Web Browser control in a TabControl.I want to set the Header of the TabItem to the Document's title of the Web Browser.
I used the following code in the Navigated Event of the WebBrowser

```
dynamic doc = tabBrowser.Document; //tabBrowser is the name of WebBrowser Control
tab.Header = doc.Title;            //tab is the name of the Tab Item
```

But this piece of code doesn't work as it should.The header changes only for a few site.
How can i set the Header of the tabItem to the Document's Title Value?

Here is the navigated function:

```
    public void tabBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) 
    { 
       urlTextBox.Text = tabBrowser.Source.ToString(); 
       myHistory.addToHistory(tabBrowser.Source.ToString());
       BookMarks.addBookmark(tabBrowser.Source.ToString()); 
       dynamic doc = tabBrowser.Document; 
       tab.Header = doc.Title; 
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain each time that the page has fully rendered and loaded each time? Please note, that any website that dynamically changes their title will also not work, could you provide some surrounding code as well please? e.g. the code where you perform your navigate and handle the navigation event?

Comment: Here is the navigated function                                      `public void tabBrowser_Navigated(object sender,     System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            urlTextBox.Text = tabBrowser.Source.ToString();
            myHistory.addToHistory(tabBrowser.Source.ToString());
            BookMarks.addBookmark(tabBrowser.Source.ToString());
            dynamic doc = tabBrowser.Document;
            tab.Header = doc.Title;

        }`

Answer (score 3):

In my code I used LoadCompleted event of WebBrowser. Probably in your Navigated Event document still not ready and document title not right or empty.

```
private void MyWebBrowser_LoadCompleted_1(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MyTextBox.Text = MyWebBrowser.Source.ToString();
        Title_doc.Content = ((dynamic)MyWebBrowser.Document).Title;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will work

```
var docTitle = document.getElementsByTagName("title")
    .Cast<IHTMLElement>()
    .FirstOrDefault().innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(dynamic)Document` cast fails atleast when the Document changes during the operation (Operation can't complete, NotSupportedException, reason 8070000c), which happens if user clicks links too fast.

Found another plausible solution based on the [Wpf webbrowser disable external links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961152/wpf-webbrowser-disable-external-links) question UPDATE 2 link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22943.preventing-external-links-from-opening-in-new-window-in-wpf-web-browser.aspx

The [DWebBrowserEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa768309(v%3Dvs.85)) has TitleChanged event which seems to work reliably, so adapt the code from there, and add handler to this event.

```
wbEvents.TitleChange += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents_TitleChangeEventHandler(OnWebBrowserTitleChanged);
```

The handler has just one argument, new title as string.

```
void OnWebBrowserTitleChanged(string title)
{
     // Set title where you want
}
```

A bit heavy, but i needed both of these to work...

*That linked code has other issues, like adding the event handlers again on every LoadCompleted event of WebBrowser*