# Wpf webbrowser disable external links

Tags: wpf, facebook

elI am working on a Wpf application. it contains a webbrowser where the user authenticates via Facebook. The problem is that the user is capable of clicking on links (for example: Forgot your password?) the standaard browser then open... what i want to do is to disable/block all the external links. so users can only authenticate and not navigate through the webbrowser control. I hoop you guys can help me out.

Update 1
Like suggested i can check the source of the webbrowser. So i can allow the wanted pages. but the problem are the links. they open on IE. i dont want to open them, but to block them at all
[Description image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWuFJ.jpg)

```
 private void webBrowserFacebook_Navigating_1(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {

       string huidigeLink = Convert.ToString(webBrowserFacebook.Source);
        MessageBox.Show(huidigeLink);

        // check for allowed pages
    }
```

Update 2
I was able to find a solution: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22943.preventing-external-links-from-opening-in-new-window-in-wpf-web-browser.aspx

Very slef explanatory.. thank you guys for the help!

Comment: You can put this restriction on WebBrowser onNavigationStarted Event listener. Add this listener to your browser, whenever any navigation starts you can access URL in the Event listener arguments. If matches with allowed URL's then proceed else return false. or stop navigation.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigating(v=vs.110).aspx event listener helps here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
    browser.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(browser_Navigating);
    browser.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(browser_Navigated);
}

void browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Your checks should happen here..
    Console.WriteLine("Loading Webpage !!");
}

void browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Webpage Loaded !!");
}
```

You can register for WebBrowser.Navigating Event.
Navigating event handlers are passed an instance of the [NavigatingCancelEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.navigation.navigatingcanceleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You can cancel the navigation by setting the [Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [NavigatingCancelEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.navigation.navigatingcanceleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) object to true.

Or you can invoke script or browser instance to stop loading if URL navigating doesn't matches.

```
yourWebBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.execCommand('Stop');");
```

Comment: Wow awesome. i will give it a try. i let you guys know. Thanx!

Comment: right now i cant test it. on Monday at work. but i will update the post when i do

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. I did try and i am capable of doing the checks to verify the pages. But the problem persists. In the Facebook login page is for example a link (Forgot your password?) if the user clicks these link the page open on a new page of internet explorer and not within the webbrowser user control. any ideas?