# Object does not contain a definition for links and no extension method links accepting first arguments of type links

Tags: c#, wpf

```
    private void UpdateWebsiteBrowser(string link)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (MyBrowser.Document != null)
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= MyBrowser.Document.links.length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (string.Compare(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(MyBrowser.Document.links.Item(i).href), HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(link), true) == 0)
                {
                   MyBrowser.Document.links.Item(i).Style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error in `MyBrowser.Document.Links`

> Object does not contain a definition for links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Document` is of type `object` - [WebBrowser.Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx) and hence have no property `links` or `Links`.

Depending on what you need you may get away with using `dynamic` (see [How to get the Document's Title from a Web Browser control in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819397/how-to-get-the-documents-title-from-a-web-browser-control-in-wpf) for example) or need to select elements yourself ([How to get value from any tag in web browser control using wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618739/how-to-get-value-from-any-tag-in-web-browser-control-using-wpf)) or cast to `mshtml.HTMLDocument`.